# Update Linked Server Provider

Tags: sql-server, openrowset

Is there anyway to update a linked server provider without dropping and recreating the linked server?

The linked servers' provider need to be updated from SQLNCLI10 to SQLNCLI11

A coworker has provided this script, but I'd like a sanity check on this from the community.

```
update master..sysservers set providername = 'SQLNCLI11' where providername = 'SQLNCLI10'
```

An update is necessary after upgrading these servers from 2008 R2 to 2014.

This is the error some of our stored procedures are getting when using openquery which is why we must update the provider.

> Operand type clash: datetime2 is incompatible with numeric